# V-model modifies objects with the same property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm working on a VueJS project and I'm having trouble using v-model with Objects. When I modify one of the object that is bound with v-model it modifies all the different objects with the same property name.

Here's my code:

HTML

```html
<div v-if="!editMode">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Nombre de Usuario: {{userGlobal.username}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Nombre: {{userGlobal.first_name}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Apellido: {{userGlobal.last_name}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{userGlobal.email}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">DNI: {{userGlobal.dni}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fecha de Nacimiento: {{userGlobal.birth_date}}</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-2" 
       @click.prevent="modifyModal">Modificar Informacion</button>
  </a>
</div>
<div v-else style="padding: 1px;">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="userEditable.username" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="userEditable.first_name" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="userEditable.last_name" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="userEditable.email" />
    <input type="integer" class="form-control" v-model="userEditable.dni" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="userEditable.birth_date" />
  </form>
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-success mt-2">Guardar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger mt-2" 
    @click.prevent="cancelEdit">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

Script

```
  data: function() {
    return {
      profile: 1,
      userGlobal: "",
      userEditable: [],
      editMode: false
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    this.fetchUser();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUser: function() {
      const vm = this;
      axios
        .get(
          "http://localhost:4000/api/users/96759c00-2682-11ea-827a-48ba4e44ff52"
        )
        .then(function(res) {
          vm.userGlobal = res.data.user[0];
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
    cancelEdit: function(){
      this.userEditable = this.userGlobal;
      this.editMode = false;
    },
    modifyModal: function() {
      this.userEditable = JSON.stringify(this.userGlobal)
      this.editMode = true;
    },
```

When I modify any of the form entries of `userEditable` it also modifies the `userGlobal` variable. This happens to me on other components. (I didn't code the patch function because I want to solve this issue first).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: UserEditable is just a reference to the exact same thing as userGlobal (in cancelEdit at least), so changing a property via either reference updates the one actual object.

Comment: I see now. Rookie mistake. Thanks !